# I want to test if lazy initialization is thread-safe

Tags: java, thread-safety, race-condition

I want to test if lazy initialization is thread-safe, so my code is below:

```
package LazyInit;

import java.util.Random;

public class UnThreadSafeLazyInit {

    private ExpensiveObject instance = null;

    public ExpensiveObject getInstance() {
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new ExpensiveObject();
        }
        System.out.println("instance=" + instance);
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            UnThreadSafeLazyInit  init = new UnThreadSafeLazyInit();
            Task t1 = init.new Task();
            Task t2 = init.new Task();
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(t1.getInstance() == t2.getInstance());
        }
    }

    static class ExpensiveObject {

    }

    class Task extends Thread {

        private ExpensiveObject instance = null;
        private Random rand = new Random(47);

        public void setInstance () {
            this.instance = UnThreadSafeLazyInit.this.getInstance();
        }

        public ExpensiveObject getInstance() {
            return instance;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(1000));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            setInstance();
        }
    }

}
```

In my code, every time I `new` two Thead task to call `public ExpensiveObject getInstance()`, in order to prove the two `instance` maybe not the same reference to  ExpensiveObject since race Condition.
When I ran it, it always return `true` by `t1.getInstance() == t1.getInstance()`.
As I know, if I don't `synchronized` the function `public ExpensiveObject getInstance()`, it could be return false since race Condition exists in Lazy Initialization.
I need to find out which code is error.
Thank you.

Comment: `t1.getInstance() == t1.getInstance()` shouldn't it be `t1.getInstance() == t2.getInstance()`?

Comment: Sorry, copy error, but the result is also true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it is not thread safe has already been covered by others. But I wanted to comment on your title: "*I want to test if lazy initialization is thread-safe*".

You can't test that a piece of code is thread safe. You might be able to find a test that proves that it is not, but testing only can't prove thread safety:

- your test might not interleave threads in a way that reproduces the problem
- your test might introduce additional synchronization (for example `System.out.println` is synchronized) that hides the actual issues
- the issue might only appear in a very rare scenario that a few test runs will probably not encounter
- the issue might only appear on certain JVMs / CPUs and the fact that your tests "works" with one specific setup does anyway not prove anything

Comment: I was about to write this answer, but yours is far better than what I would have written :)

Comment: @znlyj JBNizet's proposal outputs `false` most of the time on my machine (I've used the following constructor: `public ExpensiveObject() { try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {} }`).

Answer (score 2):

It is not thread safe, just by inspection of the code.  The problem you have is that delays of many milli-seconds is an enormous time to a computer and you are very, very unlikely to see a problem with this type of testing.

For example, the typical delay between updating a volatile field and it being visible to other threads is around 5 nano-seconds.  It is for about this long that your solution is not thread safe.  You are waiting up up to 1,000,000,000 nano-seconds to see if you get an issue.

This is like trying to see if fireworks lasting 5 seconds went off, but closing your eyes 317 years before concluding there was no fireworks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make ExpensiveObject a really expensive object:

```
public class ExpensiveObject {
    public ExpensiveObject() {
        System.out.println("I'm expensive!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000L);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("See. It took 2 seconds to create me!");
    }
}
```

Otherwise, the chance of entering into a rece condition is very small, especially since one thread is started after the other one, and thus calls `setInstance()` after the other one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Thread-safe. You're just lucky this time. Modify your code:

```
public ExpensiveObject getInstance() {
    if (null == instance) {
        System.out.println("old instance=" + instance);
        instance = new ExpensiveObject();
        System.out.println("new instance=" + instance);
    }
    return instance;
}
// In main
Thread.sleep(40); // Thread.sleep(4000);
// In run
Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(10)); // Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(1000));
```

I see a lot of `false` in my console with this code.